# Better practice to modify HTML element display via CSS classes or directly (via DOM)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm somewhat experienced in markup & styling, but I am a relative newcomer to front-end scripting.

Can someone please clarify which is better (or best) practice:

Is it better to modify HTML element display / behaviour directly via DOM or to do so by assigning and removing CSS classes?

My own take is that using javascript to append or remove CSS classes is probably the more elegant way to alter element display and / or behaviour, but I wish to confirm this before proceeding.

Can anyone comment further?

Comment: css classes is always preferable.You'd want to try and keep the HTML as clean as possible so any styling should always remain in the CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron - this is my own gut feeling too. But can you say why?

Comment: @Aaron I've always wondered about that. I mean, is there really any reason to prefer `elem.classList.add("center");` and define `.center {text-align:center}`, as opposed to simply `elem.style.textAlign = 'center';`?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the sort of thing I am trying to get my head around. Is the former really better than the latter? If so, why?

Comment: This question already has three close-votes as "primarily opinion-based", and personally I think that's your answer ;) It's down to personal opinion. My opinion is that such pedantic "separation" is daft.

Comment: The two main reasons would be -- 1. Separate content away from design .2 Making maintenance easy

Comment: @Aaron I can agree with that in the *source* HTML, but in the JavaScript that edits the current page, why is it better?

Comment: Good point. But why would you add styles through js when you could just add a class for the styles to be applied?

Comment: I only use classes when it has 2 attritbutes or more, otherwise inline style will be good enough.

Comment: @Aaron Again, I agree to some extent. I would much prefer to use `elem.classList.add("selected-item")` and define what that means in the CSS. However, if I just want to change one property, I would much prefer doing that directly on `elem.style`. My coworker takes things to a bit of an extreme, defining whole suites of classes like `.margin-left-10` that - you guessed it - sets `margin-left:10px`. This kind of pedantic separation, I feel, is daft.

Comment: Consider the case where you are not modifying just one element, but several of them in one go. Of course you could set the style on each one of them individually – but often setting a class on a common ancestor and then letting CSS do the rest of the work (via descendant or other selectors, such as `parent.specialclass foo { … }`) will be quite a bit more elegant IMHO. And another quite important thing – setting a class still let’s you take advantage of the cascade and inheritance, whereas setting a style directly is quite “absolute” and hard to work around in cases where you have to.

Comment: *setting a class still lets you take advantage of the cascade and inheritance* - that's an excellent point, @CBroe, very perceptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very general guideline:

Use classes to define some styles (or even just one style), if it actually *means* something. For instance, if you want JavaScript to designate an element as a selected item, use a `.selected-item` class and set that on the element. This lets you do design work in the CSS file.

However, if you are doing one-off modifications, especially those involving calculations, such as setting the height of an element relative to another element... then you should modify the `element.style` object with those specific properties.

In summary: Use a class if it's got meaning. Modify properties directly if it's a one-off thing.

In fact, this applies to the base HTML as well. You can easily define a class `.center {text-align:center}` and apply that to center-aligned elements, because it's not a one-off deal. But if you need for a particular element to have some extra bottom margin, use `style="margin-bottom:20px"` instead of defining a class just for that.

Comment: This says it all http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm

Comment: Thank you @Niet - that's exactly the kind of "rule of thumb" I was looking for: "If a set of display & behavioural characteristics collectively comprise an *on-page role* which may be assigned to elements, create a class and invoke javascript to add, remove or change the class. If the display or behaviour comprises of a single, atypical style declaration, add, remove or alter that style directly via the DOM."

Comment: @Aaron, just to clarify, because - forgive me if I'm mistaken - I think you misunderstood my question. I am not talking about *setting* HTML element display / behaviour, I am talking about *modifying* HTML element display / behaviour consequent to user interaction, after the page has already loaded with all element styles declared in the stylesheet etc.

Comment: @Rounin The same principle applies in both cases.

Comment: @Niet Heh. If you're a hardcore front-end scripter, yes! But I am coming from an 18-year background in markup and styling and near-zero scripting, so it never would have occurred to me to declare styles anywhere outside an external stylesheet. This time 18 months ago, I couldn't have even told you what the DOM is. Your answer above was exactly what I was looking for - thanks again.